# Email.Body not updating after editing WordEditor

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I have a form region for the reading pane. I retrieve the wordeditor for the forward mail item and then add info to the word document. This seems to work when I don't create and send the email in the same function, but when I want to create a forward email, edit it, and send it, the Email.Body doesn't update.

```
_email = this.OutlookItem as Outlook.MailItem;
private void SendForwardEmail()
{
    Outlook.MailIem fEmail = null;
    Word.Document doc = null;
    try
    {
        fEmail = ((Outlook._MailItem)_email).Forward();
        doc = GetWordEditor(fEmail);
        EditDoc(doc);
        var tmp = doc.Range().Text;
        var tmp1 = fEmail.Body;     // tmp1 won't have what I added to tmp
        ((Outlook._MailItem)fEmail).Send(); // This will send with the fEmail.Body value
                                            // and won't show edits to the word doc
    }
    finally
    {
        Release(doc);
        Release(fEmail);
    }
}
```

I use similar code in a form region for composing emails, the difference is that by the time the `Send` event is triggered, the Email.Body has updated with the edits to the word doc. I've tried `fEmail.Save()`, but doesn't seem to work. The word editor does save the work because I can access the word editor at a different point and it will still have the edits. The Email.Body just doesn't update with the changes.

EDIT: I'll add that doing the following does update the `Email.Body`, but seems like a funky solution.

```
fEmail.Display();
((Outlook.MailItem)fEmail).Close(Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olSave);
```

Answer (score 0):

Where and when do you run the code? Is it on a secondary thread?

Anyway, I'd suggest starting from releasing all underlying COM objects instantly. Use `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject` to release an Outlook/Word object when you have finished using it. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945(v=office.12).aspx) article.

Comment: The function is called during a button press event in the form region. It's not running on a secondary thread.